# How to display divs after checking password with an HTML form

Tags: php, html

I'm programming a simple password checker with a html form, where you input the code and this code is compared as hash to another hashed code in the database. If the password matches, the index.php file shows a few divs, which otherwise are completely hidden from the user.

I've tried things like:

```
 $input = "";

<center>
<form action="" method="GET">
  CODE:<br>
  <input type="text" name="code" value="">
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form> 
</center>



<?php
$checker = new Checker();
$input   = $_GET['code'];
//echo "<style>.Main_Content{ visibility:hidden;}</style>";
if ($checker->compareWords($input, 'Beginners')) {
    echo "success Beginners<br>";
    include 'Beginners_Video.php';
    echo "<style>.Main_Content{ visibility:show;}</style>";
}
else {
    echo "false Beginners<br>";
}
?>
```

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to
>   Checker::compareWords() must be of the type string, null given, called
>   in D:\www\www91\members\members.php on line 64 and defined in
>   D:\www\www91\members\checker.php:23 Stack trace: #0
>   D:\www\www91\members\members.php(64): Checker->compareWords(NULL,
>   'Beginners') #1 {main} thrown in D:\www\www91\members\checker.php on
>   line 23

The result should be no error and just the whole thing hidden, or the output "False Beginners. Nothing else"

I know that i'm just stupid and that the answer is probably really simple. I've tried and I can't figure it out.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should work once you filled in and submitted the form, but there is no check handling the case where `$_GET['code']` is unset or empty. Change your `if` statement to

```
if (!empty($input) && $checker->compareWords($input, 'Beginners')) {
```

in order to check for this first. If `!empty($input)` is `false`, the next condition won't be checked at all, so there won't be an error message and it will jump to the else clause directly.

On a side note: You should think about whether GET is the right method for what you're trying to achieve or whether POST would be better. With GET, The codes users enter might get saved in the browser's history and be visible to others using the same computer. Also, for passwords use `type="password"` for the input instead of displaying it in cleartext.

And one more thing: the `<center>` tag is deprecated and you should use CSS instead for layout.

Comment: Well it's for old people too, so they see what they're typing. It's just so they see what they are writing. Also it won't be really a password but more of a code. Password is the wrong word used here

Answer (score 0):

At the very beginning you should check if something is passed in `code` parameter, using the `isset()` method. If `$_GET['code']` is empty it will return `null` and this is why you get `must be of the type string, null given`.

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['code']) {
    $input = $_GET['code'];
} else {
  // 'code' parameter is empty
  $input = '';
}
$checker = new Checker();
// ...
```

Comment: Thank you. Now it dawns on me. Yes I've actually used isset before.